# Scope functions vs. scopes in Coroutines

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Kotlin comes with [scope functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html) and coroutines also have [scopes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scopes-in-kotlin-coroutines/). Do both scopes are related or just named equally to confuse newbies?

Comment: They are not related.

Comment: "Scope" is just a generic word and it can apply to many different technical concepts -- just like the words "order", "instruction", etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**

[Scope functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html) refer to *scope* in terms of [variable scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)).
[Coroutine scopes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scopes-in-kotlin-coroutines/) refer to *scopes* in terms of [structured concurrency](https://proandroiddev.com/structured-concurrency-in-action-97c749a8f755).
So scope functions have nothing to do with coroutine scopes and vice-versa.

**Full answer:**

*Scope* is a massivly overloaded term in computer science.

[Scope functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html) refer to *scope* in terms of [variable scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science))
That is:

```kotlin
val result = run {
   val x = 1
   val y = 2
   // x and y variables are visible here
   x + y
}
println(x) // compile-time error, variable x is not known here
```

[Coroutine scopes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scopes-in-kotlin-coroutines/) refer to *scopes* in terms of [structured concurrency](https://proandroiddev.com/structured-concurrency-in-action-97c749a8f755). In that meaning, a *scope* defines how long the coroutine you started can live.
You might start a coroutine in a global scope:

```kotlin
val globalJob = GlobalScope.launch {
   // do some fancy work here
}
```

It keeps executing until:

- you finish the job manually (`globalJob.join()` or `globalJob.cancel()`)
- the work inside launch lambda is finished
- the application process is finished - that is `GlobalScope` is finished

However, some components of your app may have shorter lifecycle than the whole application. Thus you may use eg. `ViewModelScope` which lives as long as Android ViewModel. All coroutines lauched in that scope are automatically cancelled when the lifecycle of the component (ViewModel) - and scope bound to it - ends.

Now you can see some similarities which explain why the same term - `scope` - is used in both cases:

*Scope* generally defines how long a thing lives.

So global variable is somehow similar to a coroutine launched in a GlobalScope.

However this similarity is only at the conceptual level - technically variable scoping is something completly different than coroutine scoping.

**PS**

The term *Scope* is also used in some DI frameworks (sometimes refered to as *container*), however this topic **is out of *scope*** of this answer :)